# Daisy chaining DP and HDMI

Tags: daisychaining

I want to connect two monitors (Samsung Smart M7 and Samsung LF27T700QQUXEN) to laptop which has only one HDMI port.

First monitor has two HDMI and DP 1.2, second monitor also have 2 HDMI and USB-C. Is it possible to chain them as follows:

First monitor DP -> second monitor HDMI (or USB-C) -> Laptop HDMI

or

First monitor HDMI -> second monitor USB-C) -> Laptop HDMI.

Is daisy chaining even possible with this setup?

Comment: afaik HDMI doesn't support DP at all. And I doubt laptops without a DisplayPort themselves are able to utilise that protocol.

Comment: Are you sure your laptop doesn’t support DIsplayPort over USB-C?

Comment: Not sure, promising solution seems display port to USB C, but I’m not sure if it will work

Comment: Make sure you correct your connection directions when searching cables, or you'll get the wrong thing. Signals go **from - > to**, ie computer **to** display. All yours are labelled backwards.

Comment: Right, so if I get it correctly I should be able to pass signal from PC HDMI to Display 1 HDMI and then from Display 1 Display Port 1.2 to Display 2 USB-C (or HDMI)?

Comment: No that’s totally impossible. HDMI supports exactly one display per connection. Which again brings is to the question about your laptop. You do not mention its model in your question. Please update it and include the exact make and model of your laptop.